# How can I get the scraping speed in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I was scraping a website using a pool of proxy. Few of them are pretty fast but few proxies are very slow which makes me wonder if there is any way to detect the speed of crawling the web pages (scrapedPages/minute) in a middleware so that I can discard the slower proxies.

I can see the log level `INFO` print this speed after every minute on the screen.

```
2015-12-04 11:28:50 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 10 pages (at 10 pages/min), scraped 10 items (at 10 items/min)
```

But I'm not able to get this speed in the middleware. Here's what I've tried so far.

```
class getSpeedstats(object):
    def __init__(self, stats):
        self.stats = stats

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.stats)

     def process_request(self, request, spider):
        print self.stats.get_stats()
```

The above code gives me this output:

```
{'log_count/DEBUG': 784, 'scheduler/dequeued': 408, 'log_count/INFO': 10, 'downloader/response_count': 392, 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 392, 'response_received_count': 392, 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 408, 'downloader/response_bytes': 3209679, 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 4, 3, 48, 41, 31403), 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 408, 'scheduler/enqueued': 408, 'downloader/request_bytes': 101321, 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 407, 'downloader/request_count': 407, 'item_scraped_count': 391}

{'log_count/DEBUG': 786, 'scheduler/dequeued': 409, 'log_count/INFO': 11, 'downloader/response_count': 393, 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 393, 'response_received_count': 393, 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 409, 'downloader/response_bytes': 3217865, 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 4, 3, 48, 41, 31403), 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 409, 'scheduler/enqueued': 409, 'downloader/request_bytes': 101575, 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 408, 'downloader/request_count': 408, 'item_scraped_count': 392}
```

But I still can't decipher how can I calculate the speed of the spider by this. Can anyone tell me if there is any other way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a calculated amount in the `LogStats` extension, which is basically `current_pages - previous_pages` every minute, which you can check [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/extensions/logstats.py#L36):

Now that isn't a real rate IMO, because it only takes into account that specific minute, and the total average speed would be better, for that just use:

```
pages = self.stats.get_value('response_received_count')
print pages/((datetime.now() - self.stats.get_value('start_time')).seconds/60.0)
```

So you can get the average speed of the requests/min

Comment: Thanks. That clears few of the doubts. What does this `datetime(2015, 12, 4, 9, 27, 45, 718073)` code signifies ? Is it 1 minute before the current datetime ? Or the start time of the spider ?

Comment: sorry, I was `stats.start_time`

Comment: Getting zero as output until the number of response exceeds the minutes.

Comment: Thanks @eLRuLL for your answer. The code does gives the average speed of crawling but for decision making on when to consider a proxy slower while doing a Broad Crawling(In which ip changes at some interval ) it was difficult to analyze which proxy is slower. The link that you provided does solved the problem in my case for calculating the speed.